# How can I make a Redstone elevator in Minecraft Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I just finished my Ultimate Survival Home but the problem is that I have used the staircase/ladder to move through the floors - I have 12 floor, so it's annoying to walk that far.
That's why I have been wondering how to make an effective Redstone elevator that doesn't malfunction.

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: I can't give you a good way to make a redstone elevator, but a soulsand + water elevator works pretty good imo.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Consider expanding that into an answer if you believe it would solve this problem

Comment: @WriggleniteI might, though I was just going to keep it as a comment because the poster asked for a redstone elevator.

Comment: @ShadowZ Even if this isn't exactly the solution the OP asked for, in the end the result is the same. You could answer it as a frame challenge answer like it is pretty common to see in [RPG SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/). The worst you can get is the OP don't accept your answer, which isn't something that bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a decent tutorial on Youtube (not my content)

created by LogicalGeekBoy.
It uses 1.13 water column mechanics, which are still used in 1.14.4 
Hope this helped!